# クラスのインスタンスをまとめた配列を作りたい

Tags: ruby

Ruby初心者です．
クラスのインスタンスをまとめた配列を作りたいです．
UnitTest時に型？のエラーも出てしまい，困っています．
ご教授宜しくお願いします．

イメージとしては以下のような感じです．

```
class Dummy

end

class UnitTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_addArray

    numOfTrials = 10

    # とりあえず配列の箱を用意
    models = []

    for num in 0 ... numOfTrials do

      dummy = Dummy.new

      models.concat(dummy)
      p models

    end 
  end
end
```

### エラーは以下です．

```
   16:      # とりあえず配列の箱を用意
   17:      models = []
   18: 
=> 19:      for num in 0 ... numOfTrials do
   20:
   21:          dummy = Dummy.new
   22:
test4.rb:19:in `each`
test4.rb:23:in `block in test_addArray`
test4.rb:23:in `concat`
Error: test_addArray(UnitTest): TypeError: no implicit conversion of Dummy into Array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array#concat` は `配列`に`配列`を結合するメソッドです。

今回やりたいことをするには

`models.concat(dummy)`ではなく、
`models.push(dummy)` もしくは `models << dummy`です。

Comment: 教えていただいた方法でできました．ありがとうございます．